# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `Notes`

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, methods

here is my repo:-
https://github.com/Punit9349/i-notebook/tree/main/src

error in components folder , notes.js.
my notes are not shown on my app, only a empty note is shown but shown in my console, also after adding new notes, once they added also added to database but will dissappear after refreshing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOCm1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is because `_id` attribute on note is not unique. You hardcoded `_id` for note when you add new, which will throw you that warning. Key must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

I think your github I-notebook project is not updated I checked it
use my repo to debug = [Inotebook](https://github.com/Ganesh-Rathor/INotebook/blob/master/src/components/)

try to give different key  to note